# Accessing individual elements of arow in a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-cursoradapter

I have custom cursor adapter named CAdapter having the following lines of code.

```
public class CAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView titleTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        titleTV.setText("#"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1)))+" "+
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)))); 
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_layout, parent, false); 
        return retView;
    }

}
```

The  row_item_layout.xml file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an activity FavListActivity which contains the listview. My question is how do I access the textview within the listview in order to change the color of text in that textview. I have to run that code on creation of activity (not from within the onItemClickListener). Do ask for additional info if required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what mechanism you're using to determine what row in the list you're interested in changing. Here are a couple of options:

```
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)listView.getChildAt( 0 ).findViewById(findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        //do something with the TextView
```

Or if you're in a click listener, perhaps

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        //do something with the TextView

    }
} );
```

Comment: What code shall I write in FavListActivity? I didn't get your answer.

Comment: `TextView titleTextView = (TextView)listView.getChildAt( 0 ).findViewById(R.id.listTitle);` doesn't work